# primefaces 3.2 menuItem error

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have 3 forms each with  component containing datatables. I wish to combine them into a single form (as each form contains the same set of UI components). I thought of using `<p:menu>` for this purpose. `<p:menu>` with 3 menuItems and on click of each item, appropriate form content should be rendered. but when I specify the action attribute of `<p:menu>`, I get the following error:

> Element type "p:menuitem" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

xhtml code:

```
<h:form id="frm">
  <p:menu>
    <p:menuitem value="price losers" action="#{equityBean.onType("losers")}"/>
    <p:menuitem  value="price gainers"/>
    <p:menuitem  value="price volume"/>
  </p:menu>
  <p:tabView activeIndex="#{equityBean.activeIndex}">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{equityBean.onChange}" update=":frm"/>
    <p:tab title="NSE">                   

      <p:dataTable value="#{equityBean.scripList}" var="scrip">
        ....                        
      </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="BSE">
      <p:dataTable value="#{equityBean.scripList}" var="scrip">
        .....
      </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
  </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

bean code:

```
public void onType(String type)
{
    this.type=type;
}

public List<MasterScrip> getScripList() {

   if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("losers"))
   {
    scripList=new ArrayList<MasterScrip> ();
    scripList=getScripByPriceLosers(exchange);
    return scripList;
   }
   else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("gainers"))
   {
    scripList=new ArrayList<MasterScrip> ();
    scripList=getScripByPriceLosers(exchange);
    return scripList;
   }
   else
   {
    scripList=new ArrayList<MasterScrip> ();
    scripList=getScripByVolumeType(exchange);
    return scripList;
   }
}
```

where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape quotes in strings.  Specifically, this

```
"#{equityBean.onType("losers")}"
```

Is invalid as `"#{equityBean.onType("` is parsed as the value, then the parser has an error as `losers` is not a valid continuation

You need to write

```
"#{equityBean.onType(&quot;losers&quot;)}"
```

or

```
'#{equityBean.onType("losers")}'
```

The first *escapes* the quote, the second uses an alternative string delimiter (`'` instead of `"`), so it does not clash with the quote within the string

Comment: thanks it worked! but now am facing another issue which i am posting in new question